# Can a mangaka continue another mangaka's manga?

Tags: manga-production, mangaka

There are plenty of manga that never had an ending for many reasons. For example, **High School of the Dead**'s mangaka, Daisuke Satou, [has passed away](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2017-03-26/high-school-of-the-dead-manga-creator-daisuke-sato-passes-away-at-52/.113968). Some mangaka also cannot continue their work because of health problems, as well as other reasons. Say the original mangaka either prepared or did not prepare an ending himself/herself, can another mangaka continue their work? Has this ever happened before?

Comment: Things to consider: there's gotta be an element of professional pride, fans rejecting another author's take on their beloved work, intellectual property rights need to be managed somehow, it would be basically headcanon by a fan (albeit a huge one and a pro mangaka at that).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it can. It is usually up to the publisher if they want to pursue continuing a series, depending on who owns the rights (family member tend to have a say in it as well).

Note that for HotD, the plot creator was known to be a slow writer to begin with (2 years between vol. 6 and 7), and the manga was on hiatus for quite a while before his death (2011). While his death was the nail in the coffin, I don't think anyone really expected the series to ever be completed. The artist moved on to create Triage X, which basically was written as a replacement for HotD.

Below are some examples (though I'm sure there are more).

> Cases where the author died, and his team took over:
>   [Crayon Shin-chan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crayon_Shin-chan#Manga)
>
> Cases when the author changed, even when the previous is still alive (though it is technically a new series or spin-off):
>   [Lupin the 3rd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Lupin_the_Third_manga)
>   [Saint Seiya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Seiya#Manga)
>
> Cases where the artist died, but the original author was still alive:
>   [Catapillar](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A2%E3%83%A9%E3%82%AF%E3%83%8B%E3%83%89) (They replaced the artist with another one)
>
> Cases where they had someone else fill in for the dead author:
>   [Familiar of Zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Familiar_of_Zero#Light_novels)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible but isn't easy...

- **If the first mangaka is still alive.**

Then he/she needs to find someone willing to finish his/her manga, also the publisher needs to agree as well. Then it's possible.

- **If the first mangaka is no longer alive.**

Then all the people who hold the rights to the manga (family, publishers) need to agree to let another mangaka finish the first ones work. But I don't know of any examples where the second mangaka agreed to finish the firsts manga without a manuscript or knowledge of how the story was supposed to continue.

**Reference:**

- https://godanimereviews.com/mangaka-unable-continue-manga/